# All Jekyll's functions don't work any more

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Jekyll used to work on my computer. But after I tried to install octopress, it doesn't work any more.
I do not know where is the problem but when I try anything else on terminal, it gives this output.

```
seniorokur@dell-Inspiron-5521:~/Masaüstü$ jekyll new sds
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/tags/highlight.rb:11: warning: already initialized constant Jekyll::Tags::HighlightBlock::SYNTAX
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/tags/highlight.rb:11: warning: previous definition of SYNTAX was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/tags/include.rb:16: warning: already initialized constant Jekyll::Tags::IncludeTag::VALID_SYNTAX
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:18: warning: previous definition of VALID_SYNTAX was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/tags/include.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant Jekyll::Tags::IncludeTag::VARIABLE_SYNTAX
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:19: warning: previous definition of VARIABLE_SYNTAX was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/tags/post_url.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Jekyll::Tags::PostComparer::MATCHER
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/tags/post_url.rb:4: warning: previous definition of MATCHER was here
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/bin/jekyll:16:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `require_from_bundler' for Jekyll::PluginManager:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

I couldn't search something for solving the problem because I do not know what is the problem. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you have installed jekyll via packagemanager and also via gem

uninstall the packagemanager version with

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge jekyll
```

and install the gem again:

```
sudo gem install jekyll jekyll-watch
```

Comment: But if you, like me, want distro version of Jekyll, uninstall all the local jekyll-* gems (list them by `gem query --local`) and also remove them from `/usr/local/bin`. Then you can reinstall jekyll from the repo (`sudo apt-get install jekyll`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a collision somewhere

Try a :

```
gem cleanup jekyll
gem update
```

Edit:

You have one `jekyll in /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/` and one in `/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/` I think the first one needs to be removed.

Comment: It did not work unfortunately. I also try unistall jekyll and ruby but again it did not work.

Comment: I did. But now it says: ```
seniorokur@dell-Inspiron-5521:~/Masaüstü/site/sa$ jekyll build --watch
Configuration file: /home/seniorokur/Masaüstü/site/sa/_config.yml
            Source: /home/seniorokur/Masaüstü/site/sa
       Destination: /home/seniorokur/Masaüstü/site/sa/_site
      Generating... 
                    done.
jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  uninitialized constant Jekyll::Watcher
```

Comment: @TalhaOkur run `gem install jekyll jekyll-watch`